# template database "template1" has a collation version, but no actual collation version could be determined

Tags: database, postgresql, collation, postgresql-12, postgresql-15

I just upgraded my Postgres from 12 to 15 and I keep getting this error:
`template database "template1" has a collation version, but no actual collation version could be determined`

Here's the template1 collation info in Postgres 15:
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Please let me know if any more information is required.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here's the OS information:
Distributor ID: Debian.
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).
Release: 10.
Codename: buster.

I have a Postgres docker container so I used this to upgrade: https://github.com/tianon/docker-postgres-upgrade/tree/master/12-to-15

I did not change machines or do an OS upgrade. Here's the template1 collation info on PG 12:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

So I did some digging and it turns out that the en_US.utf8 collation does not exist in the pg_collation table on Postgres 12. However on Postgres 15, it does exist in that table and has a version of 2.31:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: To your question add the answers to 1) OS and version. 2) How did you upgrade? 3) Did you change machines or do an OS upgrade? 4) What is/was the template1  information for the 12 instance?

Comment: Try `ALTER DATABASE template1 REFRESH COLLATION VERSION;`

Comment: And rebuild any indexes you created in `template1`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've updated with additional info

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried that but I got an error: ERROR:  invalid collation version change

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't have any indexes in template1

Comment: Then you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: I don't know Docker well enough, but my suspicion is that it might have something to do with `FROM postgres:15-bullseye` in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I did some investigating and have updated the original post.

Comment: @buddy2891 I saw this in a very similar situation, using the alpine image for pg 15. Switching to the debain (and libc) version made this problem go away for me. If you're showing a "locale provider" of libc under alpine, that's amost certainly wrong.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest working solution is to update collation version of template1 data base.

Login into postgres:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Look list of databases:

```
\l
```

If you see your template1 data base. Upgrade collation version:

```
ALTER DATABASE template1 REFRESH COLLATION VERSION;
```

Quite postgres cli:

```
\q
```

Reload postgres service(for Ubuntu Linux etc):

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Check postgres service status:

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

Maybe you will need to update collation version of postgres databse. Use the same steps with command:

```
ALTER DATABASE postgres REFRESH COLLATION VERSION;
```

Answer (score 4):

1. remove indexes
2. `alter database template1 refresh collation version;`
3. add/rebuild indexes